# Receiving "Firebase.set failed" when passing geocoder results from Google Maps API to Firebase

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to use Firebase to store geolocation data based on a user's address using the Google Maps Javascript API. This data would then be used to create a new marker on the map based on the lat/lon returned from the geocoder function. However, I am receiving the following error when passing the results of the function to `set()` :

> Uncaught Error: Firebase.set failed: First argument contains a function in property '0.geometry.location.lat' with contents: function (){return a}

Any help with this would be appreciated.  This is the code that I have so far:

```
function setMarkers(map) {

  var marker;
  var address;
  var submit = document.getElementById("submit");
  var fbase = new Firebase("myref");

  var image = {
   url: "images/pallette.png",
   size: new google.maps.Size(45, 52),
   origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
  }

  submit.addEventListener("click", function () {
   address = document.getElementById("address").value;
    geocoder.geocode({ "address": address}, function(results, status)   {
      fbase.child("currentMarker").set(results);
      if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          position: results[0].geometry.location,
          icon: image
        });
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: What are you wanting to pass from the `results` array to Firebase?  [Check the docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#GeocodingResults); it includes `google.maps` built-in objects like LatLng, which won't necessarily be something easily used by any external system.  It sounds like you maybe just want the address, in which case perhaps `fbase.child("currentMarker").set(results[0].formatted_address)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `results` contains a function for `geometry.location.lat`, which is not valid as a value for Firebase (since it can only store JSON). I'm not really sure why that is, but the [Google maps geocoding example on this page](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/geocoding-simple) does the same.

Try:

```
geocoder.geocode({ "address": address}, function(results, status)   {
  fbase.child("currentMarker").set(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(results)));
```

When I do that on the page above, it effectively converts the functions into their results. And since those are valid JSON, it can be stored in Firebase.